# R - Time Spent in Interval

Tags: r, datetime, time, dataframe

I have a data frame of start and end dates/times, like so:

```
start_date <- c("20/09/2016 01:20" , "22/09/2016 01:20", "28/09/2016 22:16",  "16/09/2016 21:01")
end_date <- c("20/09/2016 06:20" , "24/09/2016 22:40", "29/09/2016 03:20", "16/09/2016 23:01")
df <- data.frame(start_date, end_date)
```

And some time intervals:

```
interval_start <- "21:00"
interval_end   <- "02:00"
```

I would like to create a new column in df which calculates the total number of minutes each instance spent within the interval period. For example, row 1 spent 40 minutes in the interval period.

Does anyone know how this could be achieved? Thanks.

Comment: What is the date of the interval?

Comment: There is no date, it's just hours:mins of a 24 hour clock. The time spent in the interval needs to be the total amount of time the start-end date spends between the interval, even if the period extends over multiple intervals. Hope that made sense.

Comment: Can you show expected output based on example data?

Comment: Whew. That was truly epic time manipulation. Please see my answer.

Comment: As far as I can see, the expected output would be c(40, 740, 224, 120). Is that correct?

Comment: I think you are correct, shosaco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my short solution (in contrast to the other answers ;-) )
I also used the `lubridate` package:

```
library(lubridate)
df$start_date <- dmy_hm(df$start_date)
df$end_date <- dmy_hm(df$end_date)

df$ diff <- unlist(lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x){

   sequence <- seq(df$start_date[x],df$end_date[x], by = "min")
   cum_sum <- cumsum(format(sequence, format = "%H:%M") <= "02:00" | format(sequence, format = "%H:%M") >= "21:00")
   sum <- sum(format(sequence, format = "%H:%M") <= "02:00" | format(sequence, format = "%H:%M") >= "21:00")
   n_intervals <- length(unique(cum_sum[cum_sum %in% unique(cum_sum[duplicated(cum_sum)])]))

   ifelse(cum_sum[length(cum_sum)] - cum_sum[length(cum_sum)-1] != 0, return(sum - n_intervals-1), return(sum-1))
}))

#            start_date            end_date diff
# 1 2016-09-20 01:20:00 2016-09-20 06:20:00   40
# 2 2016-09-22 01:20:00 2016-09-24 22:40:00  740
# 3 2016-09-28 22:16:00 2016-09-29 03:20:00  224
# 4 2016-09-16 21:01:00 2016-09-16 23:01:00  120
```

The idea is the following (code in `lapply`):

1. create a sequence from start to end of each interval by one minute
2. Calculate the `sum` and the `cumsum` of the condition, that all times from this sequence are in the interval "21:00" to "02:00".
3. Calculate the number of intervals in the `cumsum`to see how much different intervals are in this sequence.
4. The difficult thing is, that when `sum` is 2 long, the difference in minutes is just 1, so we always have to subtract 1. We have to do this for every interval we have found.
   In the case, that the last value of `cum_sum` is different to the second to last one, this is a addition interval and we have to subtract 1 more.

It looks very complex, but the idea behind should be clear (I hope).

Comment: Worked a treat, thank you. And thanks for the explanation for how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Package `lubridate` helps doing the job. The main problem to tackle is long time periods, where the interval occurs several times (I solved it with the inner `for` loop) and the key function is `intersect`, which gives the simple answer to the problem "Intersection of two intervals". Summing up all the intersections gives the solution per row.

```
library(lubridate)

start_date <- c("20/09/2016 01:20" , "22/09/2016 01:20", "28/09/2016 22:16",  "16/09/2016 21:01")
end_date <- c("20/09/2016 06:20" , "24/09/2016 22:40", "29/09/2016 03:20", "16/09/2016 23:01")

start_date <- dmy_hm(start_date)
end_date <- dmy_hm(end_date)

df <- data.frame(start_date, end_date)

time_spent <- c()

# loop through each row
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  row <- df[i,]
  out <- 0

  period <- interval(row$start_date, row$end_date)

  #1. Set as many intervals for this time periods as there are days
  for(day in seq(day(row$start_date) - 1, day(row$end_date), 1)){
    myInterval <- interval(dmy_hm(paste(day, 
                                        month(row$start_date), 
                                        year(row$start_date),
                                        "21:00")),
                           dmy_hm(paste(day+1, 
                                        month(row$start_date), 
                                        year(row$start_date),
                                        "02:00")))

    # calculate intersection
    timedifference <- intersect(period, myInterval)

    if(!is.na(timedifference)){
      out <- out + as.numeric(timedifference)/60
    }

  }

  time_spent <- c(time_spent, out)
}

df$time_spent <- time_spent
```

The solution is

```
> df$time_spent
[1]  40 740 224 120
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see code comments along the way. I used the `lubridate` package.

```
start_date <- c("20/09/2016 01:20" , "22/09/2016 01:20", "28/09/2016 22:16",  "16/09/2016 21:01")
end_date <- c("20/09/2016 06:20" , "24/09/2016 22:40", "29/09/2016 03:20", "16/09/2016 23:01")
df <- data.frame(start_date, end_date)


interval_start <- "21:00"
interval_end   <- "02:00"

# Convert strings to dates
library(lubridate)
df$start_date <- dmy_hm(df$start_date)
df$end_date   <- dmy_hm(df$end_date)

# Helper columns
df$day  <- day(df$start_date)
df$mo   <- month(df$start_date)
df$yr   <- year(df$start_date)
df$day1 <- day(df$end_date)
df$mo1  <- month(df$end_date)
df$yr1  <- year(df$end_date)

# Add custom start/end for first day in row
df$interval_start <- dmy_hm(paste0(df$day-1,"/",df$mo,"/",df$yr," ", interval_start))
df$interval_end   <- dmy_hm(paste0(df$day,"/",df$mo,"/",df$yr," ", interval_end))


# Add custom start/end for last day in row, if it is different
df$interval_start1 <- df$interval_start # this is just to initialize the column with the proper class
df$interval_end1   <- df$interval_end

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(!(df$mo[i] == df$mo1[i] & df$day[i] == df$day1[i])){
    df$interval_start1[i] <- dmy_hm(paste0(df$day1[i],"/",df$mo1[i],"/",df$yr1[i]," ", interval_start))
    df$interval_end1[i]   <- dmy_hm(paste0(df$day1[i],"/",df$mo1[i],"/",df$yr1[i]," ", interval_end))
  }else{
    df$interval_start1[i] <- NA
    df$interval_end1[i]   <- NA
  } 
} 

# Calculate time in intervals for first day
time1     <- difftime(df$start_date,df$interval_end, units="mins")
time1.cap <- difftime(df$interval_start, df$interval_end, units="mins")
time1[abs(time1) > abs(time1.cap)] <- time1.cap[abs(time1) > abs(time1.cap)]

# initialize class of new col
df$time1 <- difftime(df$interval_start, df$interval_end, units="mins")

# Update time1
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(df$start_date[i] < df$interval_end[i]){
    time1     <- difftime(df$start_date,df$interval_end, units="mins")
    time1.cap <- difftime(df$interval_start, df$interval_end, units="mins")
    time1[abs(time1) > abs(time1.cap)] <- time1.cap[abs(time1) > abs(time1.cap)]

    df$time1[i] <- time1[i]*-1
  } else{

    if(df$start_date[i] > df$interval_end[i])  {
      time1     <- difftime(df$start_date,df$interval_end+86400, units="mins")
      time1.cap <- difftime(df$interval_start, df$interval_end+86400, units="mins")
      time1[abs(time1) > abs(time1.cap)] <- time1.cap[abs(time1) > abs(time1.cap)]

      df$time1[i] <- time1[i]*-1
    }
  }
}

# initialize class of new col

df1 <- df[!is.na(df$interval_start1),]
df1$time2 <- difftime(df1$interval_start, df1$interval_end, units="mins")

# create time2 for last day, if different
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  if(df1$end_date[i] < df1$interval_end1[i]){
    time2     <- difftime(df1$end_date,df1$interval_end1, units="mins")
    time2.cap <- difftime(df1$interval_start1, df1$interval_end1, units="mins")
    time2[abs(time2) > abs(time2.cap)] <- time2.cap[abs(time2) > abs(time2.cap)]

    df1$time2[i] <- time2[i]*-1
  } else{

    if(df1$end_date[i] > df1$interval_end1[i])  {
      time2     <- difftime(df1$interval_start1,df1$end_date, units="mins")
      time2.cap <- difftime(df1$interval_start1, df1$interval_end1+86400, units="mins")
      time2[abs(time2) > abs(time2.cap)] <- time2.cap[abs(time2) > abs(time2.cap)]

      df1$time2[i] <- time2[i]*-1
    }
  }
}

# See if there were any days in between first and last and if so add time
time2 <- minutes(300 * round(difftime(df1$end_date,df1$start_date, units = "days")))+minutes(time2)*-1

df$time2 <- as.period(NA)
df$time2[!is.na(df$interval_start1)]  <- time2
df$time2[is.na(df$interval_start1)]   <- 0

df$time_in_interval <- minutes(df$time1)+df$time2
df$time_in_interval
```

Note that 86,400 is the number of seconds in a day, so that's what that number was.

Comment: Wow, impressive solution. That gives an output of 240 min for the second row, which would be 3 hours. But there are more than 2 intervals in this timespan, each lasting 5 hours, so the solution should be 700 min for row 2. Similar problem for row three. See my solution above, or am I getting the task wrong?

Comment: @shosaco Thanks, I just edited it to add the little bit of missing logic at the end.

Comment: your output: `[1] "40M 0S"   "1040M 0S" "524M 0S"  "299M 0S" `. Different to `[1]  40 740 224 120`, which should be the correct solution?!